# How do I escape awk's built-in variables when used within heredoc

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Following is the command I am trying to execute :

```
while read api; do
echo $api
ssh username@ip <<ENDSSH
grep $api /myserver/logs/server.log | awk '{print $8}'| sort -n | awk 'BEGIN{i=0} {s[i]=$1; i++;} END{print "=== PERCENTILES ==="; print "50: " s[int(NR*0.50-0.5)]; print "70: " s[int(NR*0.70-0.5)]; print "80: " s[int(NR*0.80-0.5)]; print "90: " s[int(NR*0.90-0.5)]; print "95: " s[int(NR*0.95-0.5)]; print "99: " s[int(NR*0.99-0.5)]; print "100: " s[int(NR-1)]; print "Count:" NR; print "==================="}'
ENDSSH
done <apiList >output.out
```

I want to run this for multiple apis on a remote host and collect the output in an output file locally.
list of files is locally stored.

Initially I was using <<'ENDSSH' then $api wasn't getting evaluated.
now I changed that to <

How do I tell the remote host to evaluate NR?

Comment: Given that your argument to awk is enclosed in single quotes, there should be no problem: use dollars if needed, or other special characters.

Comment: it worked. just had to use slashes with $8 and $1 (\$8, \$1). :)

Answer (score 0):

In shell, backslash `\` can be used to quote, e.g. `... print "Count:" \$NR; ...`.